# Default font for RDLC report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, rdlc

Is it possible to set default font in RDLC report ?
I have report where i want to change font by I don't want to change it in every element of the report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to change the font used for the entire report using the design interface. However if you are trying to replace one font with another, e.g. Tahoma with Verdana, then you can open the code view (View > Code) and do a Find and Replace there.

Note that Arial is the default font for Reporting Services reports and therefore the font is only defined in the code for fonts **other than** Arial. If you need to change from Arial to another font you will have to do this manually in the designer.

Comment: Good grief. This is not good news. What you could do (but it would be quite custom) is write a regex parser to find all text box tags which don't have a specified font and specify one. Alternatively use XML to find style nodes in each text box node and find if a font family node is specified. I'm going to try the latter.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do this. It's actually fairly simple. Backup your rdl file before starting. This answer requires a simple app to be written:

Open the rdl as an XML document.
Find all TextRun nodes.
Look for a Style node in each.
If no Style node is found, add one with a FontFamily node inside with the desired font specified.
If the Style node is found, look for the FontFamily node. If it is found you can either leave it alone or replace the value with the desired font, depending on your requirement. If there is no FontFamily node, add it with the specified font.

ETA: I have the code and it works fabulously for me. Just note this is destructive, ie. your file will be overwritten.

```
pivate static void AddFontsToRdlc(string fileName, string defaultFont)
{
  if (!File.Exists(fileName))
  {
    // Report file does not exist
    return;
  }
  XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
  document.Load(fileName);
  string documentNamespace = document.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI;
  XmlNodeList nodes = document.GetElementsByTagName("TextRun");
  bool foundStyle = false;
  bool foundFontFamily = false;
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
  {
    foundStyle = false;
    foundFontFamily = false;
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
    {
      if (childNode.Name == "Style")
      {
        foundStyle = true;
        foreach (XmlNode styleNode in childNode.ChildNodes)
        {
          if (styleNode.Name == "FontFamily")
          {
            // Change the font here if changing all fonts to the default font
            // Alternatively, specify what font should change to what font with a switch
            foundFontFamily = true;
            break;
          }
        }
        if (!foundFontFamily)
        {
          XmlElement fontElement = document.CreateElement("FontFamily", documentNamespace);
          fontElement.InnerText = defaultFont;
          childNode.AppendChild(fontElement);
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!foundStyle)
    {
      XmlNode styleElement = document.CreateElement("Style", documentNamespace);
      XmlElement fontElement = document.CreateElement("FontFamily", documentNamespace);
      fontElement.InnerText = defaultFont;
      styleElement.AppendChild(fontElement);
      node.AppendChild(styleElement);
    }
  }
  document.Save(fileName);
}
```

Comment: alternatively, open the rdlc file in notepad++, search for the text box elements (if it's only one or two) and enter the xml elements for font family within the style childnode. +1

Comment: jeah great!! I had put that in an simple solution here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AqgVrjYd-3PgixMJv5WqbOO5G7Zm

Answer (score -6):

Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors
then change it to your desired font.

Comment: This will set the fonts used in the Visual Studio environment. The poster is asking how to set fonts within a report.